# Jquery validation. Validate array of arrays

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validation-engine

I am using jquery validation to validate a form. It works fine when it comes to validate simple variables or even and array variable but here is the thing: I need to validate an array of arrays.

My code looks something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="phones[0][prefix]" />
<input type="text" name="phones[0][number]" />
<input type="text" name="phones[1][prefix]" />
<input type="text" name="phones[1][number]" />
```

The number of phones fields are unlimited so I might have one or more.

The validation that I need to apply consists in checking that both prefix and number are not empty for each phone.

Does anybody have and idea of how to make the validation for this case. Anything I read so far has helped me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use something like `$('input[name*=phones]')`, or `console.log($('input[name*=prefix]'))`

Comment: I am using jquery validation to validate my fields and I need to set a rule to validate these particular fields. I don't see how to do it based on your answer.

Could you please explain a little bit more?

Comment: Let me create a little example

Comment: Take a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/pmv16q8t/

Comment: I added custom rules based on the `$('input[name*=prefix]')` selector, with custom messages :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom rules, based on a `selector`; for example, this selector `$('input[name*=prefix]')` gets all the inputs that `contains` `prefix` in the input name:

```
 //custom rules
$('input[name*=prefix]').each(function(i,elem){
    $(elem).rules("add", { 
    required:true,  
    minlength:3,
    number: true,
    messages: {
      required: "Required custom input",
      minlength: jQuery.validator.format("Please, at least {0} characters are necessary"),
      number: "Only numbers custom again"
    }
  });    
})
```

> You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/pmv16q8t/